# (heroku) Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am a beginner discord bot developer who wants to host his heroku bot 24/7 on Heroku.
After approx. 1 min of deploying it, I get an error:

```
2020-12-28T11:40:54.000493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-12-28T11:40:54.024808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-12-28T11:40:54.088413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-12-28T11:40:54.121927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Code in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mano-county-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bot for Mano County!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bloxlink": "^1.6.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
    "figlet": "^1.5.0",
    "noblox.js": "^4.7.3",
    "roblox-js": "^4.0.4",
    "trello-node-api": "0.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Alex_Google214",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And yes, I am not using express.

I had a piece of code with engines

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
```

before removing that the project wasn't deploying. But after removing, it deployed and then I got the error I am willing to get helped with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your app supposed to listen for HTTP / HTTPS requests?

Comment: no idea, im not sure but i guess no. (but I actually think yes, because a guy who answered (Beppe C) said that I should define web process in my Procfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlSoM.png)

The problem was here. I had web dyno enabled and Worker disabled. But then I disabled web dyno off and turned on Worker and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You must have defined a web process in your Procfile: the web process will try to bind a port where it can be reached over HTTPS. When this doesnt happen the deployment fails.

Discord bots typically works in the backend (no HTTP access): change your Procfile to use a worker.

Comment: This is my Procfile, anything to edit?
```
Worker: node index.js
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Comment: As I see app.listen thing was wrong so I removed it.